# Refinement of face vectors of the simplicial noncrossing hypertree complexes of McCammond

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, polynomials, graph-theory

Einziger on page 65 of "[Incidence Hopf algebras: Antipodes, forest formulas, and noncrossing partitions](http://pqdtopen.proquest.com/doc/750317016.html?FMT=ABS)" presents the antipode of a noncrossing partition Hopf algebra as a graded sequence of partition polynomials, which, when the indeterminates are reindexed, are comprised of the same partition monomials of those for the refined face partition polynomials of permutahedra and associahedra and the partition polynomials for noncrossing partitions (as indicated in [this associated MO-Q](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270070/analogue-of-conic-sections-for-the-permutohedra-associahedra-and-noncrossing-p)).

These antipode polynomials, when reduced to graded polynomials in a single variable as are [A133437](https://oeis.org/A133437) to [A033282](https://oeis.org/A033282) for the associahedra and [A049019](https://oeis.org/A049019) to [A019538](https://oeis.org/A019538) for the permutohedra, apparently give the coarse face vectors of the simplicial noncrossing hypertree complexes of McCammond listed on pg. 15 of his paper "[Noncrossing Hypertrees](http://web.math.ucsb.edu/~jon.mccammond/papers/index.html)" (the polynomials of [A102537](https://oeis.org/A102537)).

The monomials of the refined face partition polynomials of the permutohedra and the associahedra label geometrically distinct faces of these convex polytopes, such as pentagons versus squares for the 2-D facets of the 3-D associahedron. See this [MO-Q](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/238186/relating-face-polytopes-of-permutohedra-to-integer-partitions) for a more explicit discussion for the permutahedra and this [MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145555/why-is-there-a-connection-between-enumerative-geometry-and-nonlinear-waves/181534#181534), for the associahedra.

What might the distinct monomials of the antipode partition polynomials designate geometrically?

(This is a cross posting of an adjunct question on MO to the [MO-Q](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/270070/analogue-of-conic-sections-for-the-permutohedra-associahedra-and-noncrossing-p) "Analogue of conic sections for the permutohedra, associahedra, and noncrossing partitions.")

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1785526/bijective-mapping-between-face-polytopes-of-permutohedra-and-partitions-of-integ

Comment: See "Hopf monoids and generalized permutohedra" by Aguiar and Ardila https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.07504